# Ubuntu 23.04 freezes completely and does not recover

Tags: freeze, 23.04

Good morning,

I moved to Ubuntu from Windows about 2 years ago, and have found it to be an absolutely brilliant OS, with the singular exception of this one issue that has been really bugging me: The entire system occasionally freezes, usually a couple of times a day.

**Symptoms:**

- The entire screen freezes. Does not recover by itself. Mouse does nothing. Keyboard shortcuts do nothing. I have to hold the power button down for 10 sec to crash it, then turn it on again, which often causes me to lose quite a bit of whatever I was working on.
- When the freezes occurs, sound output stops completely. This is different to what happens when the laptop runs out of battery, which causes the screen to freeze in the same way, but the sound to loop over the last half a second or so, until the laptop is crashed with the power button for 10 sec.
- There is no unusual CPU or RAM usage before the freeze. CPU sits at about 40%, and ram at about 60% most of the time. This does not change or spike before a freeze occurs.

**When the problem occurs:**

There is no one application that causes this freezing to occur, but it seems to be more common in a few specific cases:

- When saving a document in Libreoffice. (Happens about a fifth of the time. The file does not get saved.)
- When playing full-screen video in Firefox, especially if I have an HDMI monitor connected. (Will almost certainly happen within 5 minutes or so.)
- The freezing seems to occur more quickly when using higher resolution external monitors, but it's possible that's just coincidence.
- Interestingly, if the video is scaled to fill most of the screen, using Firefox's picture-in-picture thingo, but is not technically maximised, the freezing occurs much less frequently.

The freezing hardly ever occurs when:

- Browsing normal webpages in Firefox.
- Reading PDF documents.
- Doing Zoom calls.
- Browsing Discord, or reading emails in Thunderbird.
- Copying large files, or cloning git repositories.
  That said, I have still had freezes with nothing open apart from a text-based video game (Brogue).

**Software Details:**

- OS: Ubuntu 23.04 lunar
- Kernel: x86_64 Linux 6.2.0-35-generic
- Shell: bash 5.2.15
- DE: Xfce
- WM: Xfwm4

**Hardware details:**

- Disk: 93G / 117G (84%)
- CPU: Intel Pentium N3710 @ 4x 2.56GHz
- GPU: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 405 (BSW)
- RAM: 1142MiB / 3805MiB
- Resolution: 1366x768
- Device: Dell Inspiron laptop. 2017 model.

**What I've tried:**

- Updating everything using the GUI software updater: Done. Didn't help.
- Just waiting: Left it overnight. It didn't unfreeze.
- Alt-printscreen: Saw this in another thread about SysReq's ... doesn't seem to do anything for me, even when not frozen.

**Logs:**

Output of `journalctl -b -1 -e`:

```
~
~
lines 978-1000/1000 (END)
Oct 27 14:20:00 roni systemd[1]: user-112.slice: Consumed 5.887s CPU time.
Oct 27 14:20:04 roni bamfdaemon[1741]: Got an X error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
Oct 27 14:20:04 roni bamfdaemon[1741]: Got an X error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
Oct 27 14:20:04 roni bamfdaemon[1741]: Got an X error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
Oct 27 14:20:04 roni systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 27 14:20:08 roni systemd-resolved[492]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
Oct 27 14:20:08 roni systemd-timesyncd[493]: Contacted time server 185.125.190.58:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Oct 27 14:20:08 roni systemd-timesyncd[493]: Initial clock synchronization to Fri 2023-10-27 14:20:08.497705 AEDT.
Oct 27 14:20:08 roni onedrive[1177]: WARNING: Your onedrive client version is now obsolete and unsupported. Please upgrade your client version.
Oct 27 14:20:08 roni onedrive[1177]: Current Application Version: 2.4.23
Oct 27 14:20:08 roni onedrive[1177]: Version Available:           2.4.25
Oct 27 14:20:08 roni onedrive[1177]: Configuring Global Azure AD Endpoints
Oct 27 14:20:08 roni systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 27 14:20:09 roni systemd[1]: blueman-mechanism.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 27 14:20:20 roni nxexec[1394]: pam_unix(nx:session): session closed for user murray
Oct 27 14:20:20 roni systemd[1]: session-c4.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 27 14:20:20 roni systemd[1]: session-c4.scope: Consumed 1.772s CPU time.
Oct 27 14:20:20 roni systemd-logind[648]: Session c4 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Oct 27 14:20:20 roni systemd-logind[648]: Removed session c4.
Oct 27 14:20:20 roni nxexec[1946]: pam_unix(nx:session): session opened for user murray(uid=1000) by (uid=127)
Oct 27 14:20:20 roni systemd-logind[648]: New session c5 of user murray.
Oct 27 14:20:20 roni systemd[1]: Started session-c5.scope - Session c5 of User murray.
Oct 27 14:20:21 roni systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
~
~
```

Happy to provide any other logs / info that might be helpful?

Any suggestions would be greatly appriciated!

Thanks in advance,
Murray.

Comment: Your symptoms sound like a problem with limited resources.  A 40% CPU utilization is pretty high and a 60% RAM utilization is quite high.  How many applications do you have running?  You really don't have much RAM installed.  Size of the swapfile?   That's a REALLY small hard drive. Not the fasted Quad core CPU.  If Ubuntu is starved for resources it will start dumping processes.  Perhaps your mobo or hardware configuration is just too minimal for a multitasking OS?  No offense but that's a really low end, 6 year old laptop.

Comment: True, it's not the most powerful laptop in the world, but I don't have the spare cash to upgrade right now. I don't typically use more than 1 application at a time, and, apart from the freezing, it does the job for most of what I want to use it for. The 40% CPU and 60% RAM is when watching YouTube in Firefox. With nothing open, it uses about 15% CPU, and 25% RAM. Size of the swapfile is 2.1Gb.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

> Oct 27 14:20:08 roni onedrive[1177]: WARNING: Your onedrive client version is now obsolete and unsupported. Please upgrade your client version.
> Oct 27 14:20:08 roni onedrive[1177]: Current Application Version: 2.4.23
> Oct 27 14:20:08 roni onedrive[1177]: Version Available:           2.4.25

Whilst strictly not related to your problem, you should fix this important issue.

To install the client correctly on Ubuntu, you must follow these instructions: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md

One significant item of note is that Microsoft depreciated the use of SHA1 from the OneDrive API and the client version you are running does not contain that highly important fix that was included in v2.4.24.

As per the application advice, the latest version is v2.4.25. Please refer to https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/releases for additional details.

Your next question will be why is the Ubuntu application version obsolete .. that question needs to be asked to Ubuntu and folk that manage packages.

Out of date packages potentially contain bugs and issues that have been fixed in newer versions - and those issues can contribute to system instability .. so potentially another package, that has known issues that have been fixed, but has not been updated for Ubuntu is contributing to your issue here.

Additionally with such a small disk, as per the comment above - you really should look to replace that with at least a 512GB or 1TB SSD - it could be that the actual disk (if still the original spinning rust disk that Dell shipped the laptop with) is experiencing bad sectors and/or other issues - thus this times out the SATA connectivity bus and hangs the system (I have seen this too many times).

Comment: If it was an issue with the disc, wouldn't we expect the freezing to occur regularly when copying or moving about large files? I'd pretty much ruled out this as the problem, because I can copy about 40Gb on and off USB's without a freeze?
P.S. I hardly ever use onedrive anymore, so I might just uninstall it - but thanks for the comments anyway!